# "Signature Verification Failed" when flashing stock ROM

Tags: rom-flashing, samsung-galaxy-s-4, recovery-mode, device-firmware

When booting into recovery mode and installing a ROM zip from my SDcard, it first says I need to mount my /sdcard (when it is mounted), and then it says "signature verification failed", despite my using a stock ROM zip.

Perhaps this has something to do with my obtaining the stock(?) ROM from a possibly untrustworthy third-party site? What is the official download site for Samsung Galaxy S4 (SGH-M919) phones?

thanks in advance for the help

(cf. [my other question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/104370/39571) for more background information)

Comment: You probably have the stock recovery installed. It requires every zip to be signed with Samsung's signature to prevent users from flashing incompatible zips. Install a custom recovery like CWM, TWRP or Philz and try again.

Comment: @GiantTree: Where do I get these? thanks (and happy Easter, btw ☺). I tried [this one](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2539361), and it threw the "signature validation failed" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found [sammobile.com](http://www.sammobile.com/) a very useful site for finding firmware for samsung devices. I don't think there is an official download site.
[Here is the firmware for SGH-M919](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/SGH-M919/)

I have had the same issue before. Just trying **the same** process again fixed it for me.
You can try wiping your cache and dalvik cache but I am not sure if that will make a difference. Then retry flashing the ROM.
Also make sure you have downloaded the file correctly. Trying to Install a partially downloaded file will give you a lot of headaches!

Answer (score 0):

You can get ClockWork Mod Recovery by installing it with the Rom Manager App, from GPlay or here: https://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager

or find TWRP (my personal preference) here: http://twrp.me/Devices/

Comment: Your first option would not work for me because my phone does not boot up. I'll try out the second option. thanks

Comment: …Your second option would not work because http://twrp.me/Devices/ has .img files, not .zips.

Comment: Are you able to boot into download mode? If so, you should have no trouble installing through Odin. Follow the "Odin Install Method" here: http://twrp.me/devices/samsunggalaxys4tmobile.html

Comment: No, I cannot enter download mode, either. I can only install `*.zip`s. Things would be very easy if I could enter USB debugging mode or download mode, but I cannot because it will not reboot.

Comment: what to do if my tablet is not booting up. while flashing,  it says that signature verification failed.